# In which cases is JavaScript code rendering a post in a different way considered to be added to a single site requesting it?

Tags: support, javascript

On *Drupal Answers Meta* , [Automatically link function names to api.drupal.org](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366/automatically-link-function-names-to-api-drupal-org) has been posted months ago. In short, the feature request is to automatically link function names to documentation pages on [Drupal.org API](http://api.drupal.org).
My guess is that, as the answer to that question suggests, it would be implemented as JavaScript code.

Actually, the JavaScript code would do something more than simply replacing text with a link; for example, it would get the correct link to the documentation page, if there is one. The canonical sources for documentation on Drupal functions (which include also the functions implemented in third-party modules) are at least two, and one of these is Drupal.org API.

Some Stack Exchange sites already use JavaScript code that is normally not added to other sites: [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). Clearly that JavaScript library is used from more than one site, but I guess the number of sites using is not a problem.

Supposing that requests to add specific JavaScript code for a site are considered, in which cases are those requests full-filled?

Comment: What does that plugin do that adding in links can't? MathJax and Chess render the content different, can't be done via Markdown

Comment: It would render the content differently, changing drupal_render() in [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), or drupal_render/6 in [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/6). That is only an example; another example could be changing [#1838624] in http://drupal.org/node/1838624. The question is more generic, though. It is more JavaScript code a site could find useful, for a reason or the other, and in which cases it is considered adding it to the site.

Comment: Making words links isn't the same level of change as creating a chess board or converting it into a displayed formula. Former sounds lazy, latter beneficial to understanding

Comment: It is not the same level of change, indeed. Still, changing a function name in the correct link to the documentation page is something that could be interesting to have, especially when the canonical sources are more than one. Documentation about the functions of a module that is not part of Drupal is not found on Drupal.org API, but another site. I didn't report all the details because I don't think they are necessary to answer the question. The purpose of the question is seeing if there is any chance to implement a feature.

Comment: Not on specifics here, but guessing that the bigger the change to the page look and how integral it would be to imparting information, the better the chances

Comment: I guess it depends from the usefulness of the code too: If the code adds a graph showing how much sites are using a Drupal module, which is then visible to the users hovering the name of a Drupal module, that could probably be not acceptable, even if the change done is bigger. I guess the decision depends from other factors, such as the fact the same effect could be obtained on client side.